# Switching theme with BloC. Am I doing right?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

Hello I am trying to change theme with BloC. But not sure if it is best practice.

Here is my `switch_theme_cubit.dart`

```
class ThemeCubit extends Cubit<ThemeData> {
  ThemeCubit() : super(AppTheme.lightTheme);

  void switchTheme() {
    state == AppTheme.lightTheme
        ? emit(AppTheme.darkTheme)
        : emit(AppTheme.lightTheme);
  }
}
```

And `MaterialApp` part of `main.dart`

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => InternetConnectivityCubit()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => CounterCubit()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => ThemeCubit())
      ],
      child: BlocBuilder<ThemeCubit, ThemeData>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: Strings.appTitle,
            theme: state,
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            initialRoute: AppRouter.homeScreen,
            onGenerateRoute: AppRouter.onGenerateRoute,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It looks like [this](https://github.com/baranacikgoz/flutter_project_template_BloC) (the first part of the gif in the readme). Am I doing right ?

Comment: Is it working? If so, whats the problem? StackOverflow is more for solving issues than asking for opinions. If it works, then I guess youre doing it fine.

Comment: @Stahp you think wrong. I am trying to improve my code. Don't expect you to understand it unless you have the curious

Comment: From the StackOverflow guidelines, "**Dont ask about:** Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc." Im trying to tell you that there is no solution to your question because you seek some kind of improvement about 'best way' of doing things when Im telling you that there is no best way. You are doing it, in my opinion, one of correct ways and as far as this works and doesnt feel wrong to you its ok to leave it be like it is. Any 'better' solution will come naturally when you will further develop this app. If you want advice, dont try overdoing things perfect way.

Comment: Yes, it's alright. It is how it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, technically, this is absolutely correct.

I would suggest you make your mode a three-state. Light, Dark and System Default.

When I set my device to dark mode, I want all my apps to go to dark mode by default. I don't want to open all 37 apps and find the setting and switch them individually. The default should be that if I have not set it explicitely, it will take the value from what I have set in my system settings.